# iPhone 4.0 OS, blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iOS adventures, [I got really into blocks](http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2010/07/blocks-in-objective-c.html), because they were necessary for the [`UIViewAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) to "Animate With Blocks" which is the recommended way to do UIView animations. Of course, this results in code that is not backwards compatible. I realize this question has a subjective component, but at what point would using the iOS 4.0 code only be a good idea? Or would differential code be a good idea, and how would that be achieved in objective-c?

I'm now faced with redoing my code for iOS 3.0, which is a painful task: should I just keep my "blocks" code around until the world advances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Plausible Blocks](http://www.plausiblelabs.com/blog/?p=8) for a port of the blocks runtime to 10.5/iPhone OS 3. It might be easier than rewriting your code, though you'll have to implement and add the relevant animation methods to UIView's metaclass on 3.0 (hint: `class_addMethod()`).

I don't think we'll be dropping OS 3 support for another 6-9 months, depending on adoption (especially considering that the iPad is still stuck on 3.2.1).

There's also no easy way to replicate `setAnimationWillStartSelector:` with the block-based animation API. I've used it to sync sounds to animations (you can't just play the sound, because the animation doesn't start until after view layout/image loading finishes).

Comment: Great answer and you hit some points I didn't know about at all, like the absence of the `setAnimationWillStartSelector`... I really don't get the obsession with blocks. On one hand they're so much cuter, but on another, they almost insist on hard-to-read inline code. Obviously you can call methods...

Comment: Another question is: how long will the deprecated methods stick around (judging from historically similar cases)?

Comment: "Normal" animations haven't actually been deprecated yet, and I'd give it until at least iOS 5 (i.e. when they might drop OS 3 support from the SDK) before it's deprecated, and a while after that before it's removed. If you go for a warnings-free build, then you'll have a lot of #ifs in your code anyway (because simulator builds set min OS = base SDK), so it should automatically stop using deprecated functions when you drop the relevant base SDKs anyway,